# Is there anyway to make a Powerpoint file downloadable and readable but not editable?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, copy-protection

I know about Powerpoint's Protection features but they don't seem to meet the need. We would like to be able to offer the general public access to read the file, without needing a password, and without being able to edit it.

Thinking there might be some Javascript code or a plug-in that would do it...

Comment: Of course not, you can edit any file on your computer. You can even edit them in notepad. Best you can do is digitally sign it so edits are detectable

Answer (score 1):

You could save file as a `.ppsx` which is a PowerPoint Show file

[image]

and add a password to modify under the Tools > General Options

[image]